# Ubuntu 18.10 does not seem to find my MX150

Tags: 18.10

I currently have Ubuntu 18.10 on my Acer Swift 3 and no matter what I do I can't seem to make it recognize my MX150. If I try to install NVIDIA versions for that it says it doesn't exist, any ideas why? I am not sure what I should post but I will when I do.

Comment: Take a look in the BIOS aka UEFI to see if it's enabled.

Comment: @spacelander There is no option on the UEFI for any cards. On the advanced tab there is only "Intel VTX", "Intel VTD" and "SATA Configuration".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `nvidia-driver-430` driver from [Graphic Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)? You can then switch between Intel graphic card or MX 150 using `Nvidia X Server Settings`.

These commands may be helpful:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime
```

You can then run `NVIDIA X Server Settings` to switch between Inter or Nvidia graphic cards.

PS: I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my Acer Swift 3 with MX 250 (the same model with yours, but with higher graphic card), and I can switch between my MX 250 or Intel graphic card.